# How is Riemann–Stieltjes integral a special case of  Lebesgue–Stieltjes integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, functional-analysis

Thanks for reading! My questions are based on the following quotes from Wikipedia:

1. About [the existence of 
   Lebesgue–Stieltjes integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue-Stieltjes_integration#Definition):

   > The Lebesgue–Stieltjes integral $  \int_a^b f(x)\,dg(x)$ is defined
   >   when
   >   ƒ : [a,b] → R is Borel-measurable and
   >   bounded and g : [a,b] → R is of
   >   bounded variation in [a,b] and
   >   right-continuous, or when ƒ is
   >   non-negative and g is monotone and
   >   right-continuous.

   I was wondering if this is the right
   condition for its existence?
2. About [the existence of
   Riemann–Stieltjes integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Existence_of_the_integral):

   > The best simple existence theorem
   >   states that if f is continuous and g
   >   is of bounded variation on [a, b],
   >   then the integral exists. A function g
   >   is of bounded variation if and only if
   >   it is the difference between two
   >   monotone functions. If g is not of
   >   bounded variation, then there will be
   >   continuous functions which cannot be
   >   integrated with respect to g. In
   >   general, the integral is not
   >   well-defined if f and g share any
   >   points of discontinuity, but this
   >   sufficient condition is not necessary.
   >
   > On the other hand, a classical result
   >   of Young (1936) states that the
   >   integral is well-defined if f is
   >   α-Hölder continuous and g is β-Hölder
   >   continuous with α + β > 1.

   For the question in the part 3, I
   was wondering for Riemann–Stieltjes
   integral $\int_a^b f(x) \, dg(x) $
   to exist, must g be nondecreasing?
   It looks like not the case quoted
   above.
3. [Specialization from Lebesgue–Stieltjes integral to Riemann–Stieltjes integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue-Stieltjes_integration#Riemann.E2.80.93Stieltjes_integration_and_probability_theory):

   > Where f is a continuous real-valued
   >   function of a real variable and g is a
   >   non-decreasing real function, the
   >   Lebesgue–Stieltjes integral is
   >   equivalent to the Riemann–Stieltjes
   >   integral,

   I was wondering  why it only mentions the case when g is nondecreasing? Is this the necessary condition for existence of Riemann-Stieltjes integral?
4. Do Lebesgue–Stieltjes integral and
   Riemann–Stieltjes integral generally
   use the same notation $  \int_a^b f(x)\,dg(x)$? How does one
   know which one the notation refers
   to?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think my understanding is completely correct and should have posted as a comment, but it has length restrictions.

1. It seems to me that when $g$ is BV and right continuous, and $f$ is Borel measurable, $f$ does not have to be bounded. There are unbounded Lebesgue integrable functions, so the same should be true for Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral, which is just Lebesgue integral w.r.t. the signed measure $\mu_g$ on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ induced by $g$.
2. It should be OK for function $g$ with bounded variation. We can write $g$ as the difference of two non-decreasing functions.
3. I don't think Riemann-Stieltjes integral requires the integrator to be non-decreasing. It might be BV or possibly  an even broader class of functions. I guess the author of Wikipedia entry mentions only nondecreasing functions because s/he has CDF of a random variable in mind and wants to discuss its application in probability theory.
   I also have the impression that these two integrals agree whenever the Riemann-Stieltjes integral exists. (Just like the relation between the Lebesgue integral and the Riemann integral.)
4. If these two notions agree, there's no danger of using the same notation. Otherwise, I've seen authors using prefix to distinguish different types of integrals, e.g., $(R)\int_a^b...$ for Riemann(-Stieltjes) integrals.

Comment: Thanks! For 2, I was wondering if $g$ being non-decreasing implies $g$ having bounded variation? Do I need to specify both are over an interval $[a,b]$?

Comment: (1) $g$ nondecreasing implies it has bounded variation, because the total variation of $g$ on $[a,b]$ is always $g(b)-g(a)$ regardless of the partition. In fact, "A function $g$ is of bounded variation if and only if it is the difference between two monotone functions." (2) Yes, we are talking about functions on $[a,b]$.